# Go to Specific URL depending on what button was previously clicked using Javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have 3 buttons: Purchase option 1, Purchase option 2, & Purchase option 3. Each button will open up the same Disclosure Modal which has an "accept" button.

Depending on which option the user selects, I want to direct the user to different URL once they click "accept".

For instance if they click "Purchase Option 1", then clicks "accept" they will go to www.purchaseoption1.com etc etc...

HTML Buttons:

```
<button type="button" id="option1" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#disclosureModal">
  Purchase option 1
</button>

<button type="button" id="option2" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#disclosureModal">
  Purchase option 2
</button>

<button type="button" id="option3" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#disclosureModal">
  Purchase option 3
</button>
```

Disclosure Modal:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="#disclosureModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Disclosure</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Disclosure Content
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Decline</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Accept</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My thinking is grabbing the id of the button clicked, storing it as a variable, then use if/else if statements to direct users. Now I need help putting it into code.

Answer (score 0):

you can add 3 radio buttons or check box in the Modal and then check before button click

Answer (score 0):

You have the same `button` that invokes the `modal`. If I were to do this I would rather give them the same class and put a data in the attributes.

Something like follows

```
<button type="button" data-option="option1" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btnoption" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#disclosureModal">
  Purchase option 1
</button>

<button type="button" data-option="option2" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btnoption" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#disclosureModal">
  Purchase option 2
</button>

<button type="button" data-option="option3" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btnoption" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#disclosureModal">
  Purchase option 3
</button>
```

This way I can write a minimal code to get the option

```
$(function(){
   $('.btnoption').click(function(){
        var option = $(this).attr('data-option');
        // Do the rest of the stuff.
    });

});
```

You can have a hidden field in your code and put this option value in that field so that you can check it later.